# Sharepoint Web Part Error CS1061

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, asp.net

My web parts deployed yesterday morning very well. Cant recive code in my ascx. now getting error like this :

```
Error   CS1061  'announcementdescription_announcementdescription_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'objDescription' and no accessible extension method
```

[image]

Comment: There should be a code behind file for your UserControl named AnnouncementDescription.ascx.cs. Does it contain a property/field with the name objDescription?

Comment: yes contains.But still same..

Comment: Is your objDescription public/protected?

Comment: my objDescription is protected